# clonezilla copy log-file(s) to usb-device

Tags: linux, shell, logging, clonezilla

i want to create/restore an image of a system completely unattended with an clonezilla-live usb-stick. So far the unattended backup/restore works fine. I just plug in the stick, boot up the pc and after the work is done the pc shut down.

Now i need an confirmation that the backup/restore was successfull. 
For this purpose i want to execute an shell script which copy the log-file into an specific file to a other partition on the usb-stick after the work is done.

I tried to execute the script as postrun-method in the syslinux.cfg but this always led to an error. 
Furthermore i tried it with drbl-ocs but i'm not sure if i did it right.

here is the shell script i want to execute:

```
#!/bin/sh

#############
/opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-sr -q2 -j2 -z1p -i 4096 -p true savedisk img sda
#############
dir=/home/partimag/logs/

time=$(date +"%H-%M-%S")    # current time
i=$(ls -l $dir | wc -l)     # index

# create log-directory if it didn't exist
if [ ! -e $dir ] 
then
    sudo mkdir $dir
fi

# create new log-directory (
sudo mkdir $dir/$i"_"@$time

# copy all log-files to the created directory
sudo cp /var/log/* $dir/$i"_"@$time

# shut-down the machine
sudo shutdown -h now
```

the first instruction (after the shebang) was my attempt to use the drbl-ocs but i have not really an idea what this is. I believe it's another interpreter which can handle shell scripts too.. Am i right ?

an here is the syslinux.cfg i use:

```
append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live username=user config quiet noswap     edd=on nomodeset nodmraid noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=NONE ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/" ocs_prerun1="mount --bind /mnt/ /home/partimag/" ocs_live_run="/lib/live/mount/medium/syslinux/clonezilla.sh" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="yes" vga=788 ip=  nosplash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
```

please help ! 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it :)

the only thing to do was to add the interpreter in front of the ocs_live_run method.

Now the syslinux.cfg looks like this:

```
append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live username=user config quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset nodmraid noeject locales=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-layouts=NONE ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/" ocs_prerun1="mount --bind /mnt/ /home/partimag/" ocs_live_run="bash /lib/live/mount/medium/syslinux/clonezilla.sh" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="yes" vga=788 ip=  nosplash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
```

please rate if this was usefull for you :)